# N-ary decision tree with categorical features

Tags: classification, decision-trees, categorical-data, categorical-encoding, cart

I want to build an n-ary decision tree with categorical features.
I am using ordinary ID3 algorithm to build a tree.

Lets take the next dataset as a training dataset for building a decision tree:

| dors | age | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 | 1 |

A decision tree will look as such:

[image: decision tree]

Lets say now in test or prod time, an example comes with features `dors=3 age=4` our tree cannot classify this example even though it has seen examples where `doors=3` and examples where `age=4`.
My implementation throws an error that value is missing and sklearn implementations of decision trees are always binary trees.
Overall it cannot be expected that we covered all possible combinations in training set so there could always be examples in test set with unique combination of feature values which our tree cannot classify.
How can this problem be solved and what are some solutions for solving it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your features are not really categorical, at least `age`: with categorical features the possible values are known at training, so normally you cannot have a case like this (otherwise it means that the training set is not large enough, so not representative).

However this can happen with numerical features. But with numerical features the condition on the node 'age' would not be `if age==5 then...` as in the categorical case, it would be for instance `if age < 5.5 then ...`. Such a condition can handle the case `age=4`.

Comment: Its true that I didn't specify it but you can look at `age` as a categorical feature with values `4=new_car 5=old_car 6=very_old_car` and same thing would apply. Does that just mean that training set is not large enough? It seems to me that with much many features the chances of having a "representative" training set decrease. Is there a way to fight this?

Comment: @dzi A categorical variable has only a finite number of values, so increasing the size of the training set with random instances is guaranteed to reach the full set of values at some point. Supervised learning relies on the assumption that the training set is a representative sample, but If you have 3 possible values but the training set contains only two, it's definitely not a representative sample for your data.

Comment: But there are all 3 possible values in training set, there just isnt a combination of all possible values for number of doors and age. Expecting all possible combinations of all features to be present isnt realistic

Comment: @dzi oh ok, I think I see your confusion: in a binary decision tree the conditions are like `if feature==value then ... else ...`, i.e. any other value goes to the 'else' statement. In ID3 each node is indeed supposed to lead to every possible value of the variable, I don't see why this would be unrealistic. It's possible that a variable is never selected, but for any selected variable all of its values must be represented.